# splitting NSString element based on the special character in iphone

Tags: iphone

I'm getting a string from xml as |Name|Id|Address|  I want only the contents which are inside "|" that is Name and Address should be added to one array,Id should come in different array.How to split this string in to the array required

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSArray *strComp = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

This should give you an array containing [@"Name", @"Id", @"Address"]

You can then sort in to separate arrays as necessary.

Hope this helps to get you on your way!

Comment: Plus it will add two empty string objects as first and last object of the array. So they need to be removed as well if necessary.

Comment: good answer and good comment by @Desdenova.  filter the array with NSPredicate to remove empty strings, assuming you don't want them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The string i'm using comes from the backend.So "Id" may come in the first place like  |Name|Id|Address| or  Id|Name||Address|.I want "Id" which is not inside pipe("|").But when i use [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]; it gives all the values including "id".But i want the elements which are inside pipe["|"] that is i need only "Name" and "Address"

Comment: So for clarification, the separate elements are "Id", "|Name|" and "|Address|"? How much control do you have over the back-end? Could you send them with a separator character, such as ',' to make the list you receive for example, "|Name|,Id,|Address|" or id,|Name|,|Address|"? This would make this problem much easier to solve